# How to remove duplicates from second select using union sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: outfits and reactions. I need to display the first 6 outfits from a specific user that has liked specific outfits in the last 48hours then the rest of the outfits. This works great but I get duplicates from the second query where I repeat these outfits again. I want to make sure outfit.id is unique.

How can I remove these duplicates?

```sql
(select outfit.id,
        outfit.title,
        ro.type,
        ro.outfit_id,
        ro.sub,
        ro.created_at as reaction_created_at,
        0 as priority
 from outfit
          left join reaction_outfit ro on outfit.id = ro.outfit_id
 where ro.sub = '123' and ro.created_at >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '48 hours')
 order by reaction_created_at desc nulls last LIMIT 6)
union
(select outfit.id,
        outfit.title,
        ro.type,
        ro.outfit_id,
        ro.sub,
        ro.created_at as reaction_created_at,
        1 as priority
 from outfit
          left join reaction_outfit ro on outfit.id = ro.outfit_id
 where is_public = true
 order by outfit.created_at desc)
order by priority, outfit_created_at desc;
```

Postgres version 13.2

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and reveal which column(s) define a "duplicate."

Comment: I want to make sure the outfit.id is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By its definition, the `priority` column will thwart the union's ability to remove duplicates, as the two halves of the union will never be duplicate.  You may try using a `DISTINCT ON` approach here:

```sql
select *
from
(
select distinct on (id) *
from (
(select
     outfit.id,
     outfit.title,
     ro.type,
     ro.outfit_id,
     ro.sub,
     ro.created_at as reaction_created_at,
     0 as priority
 from outfit
 left join reaction_outfit ro on outfit.id = ro.outfit_id
 where ro.sub = '123' and ro.created_at >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '48 hours'
 order by reaction_created_at desc nulls last
 limit 6
)
union
(select
     outfit.id,
     outfit.title,
     ro.type,
     ro.outfit_id,
     ro.sub,
     ro.created_at,
     1
 from outfit
 left join reaction_outfit ro on outfit.id = ro.outfit_id
 where is_public = true
)
) t
order by id, priority
) t
order by priority, reaction_created_at desc;
```

Comment: The issue with removing priority is that the final query is re-ordered by the outer order statemant: `order by reaction_created_at desc;`  and the ordering of the two sub queries seems to be ignored.

Comment: I tried to remove outer order statement `order by reaction_created_at desc;` then the order is still not correct..

Comment: @Anita Please try the updated answer, which should at least get close to what you want.

Comment: Thank you Tim for updating your answer. I tried that and it's not ordered by priority. I got 1,1,0,1 etc.. I tried to re-order the outer statement:  `order by priority, id, title, type, outfit_id, sub, reaction_created_at;` but that gives me an error.

Comment: I got this error: `ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expression`

Comment: I updated my answer and it should at least give you the correct result set.  You might need to subquery again and order by date if you require that.

Comment: Would that order by id and not priority?

Comment: `order by id, priority` as used here will choose the _lower_ priority record assuming there be two records for the same `id`.  It can't be changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the results are not ordered by priority. I have 1,1,0.. etc..

Comment: Then you need to wrap my answer and subquery, this time using whatever order you want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but is this as straightforward as adding distinct to solve your problem?

Edit - removed priority column as called out by Tim, as this will indeed prevent duplicates from being removed where they have different priorities.

```
    Select distinct * from(
(select outfit.id,
        outfit.title,
        ro.type,
        ro.outfit_id,
        ro.sub,
        ro.created_at as reaction_created_at
 from outfit
          left join reaction_outfit ro on outfit.id = ro.outfit_id
 where ro.sub = '123' and ro.created_at >= (NOW() - INTERVAL '48 hours')
 order by reaction_created_at desc nulls last LIMIT 6)
union
(select outfit.id,
        outfit.title,
        ro.type,
        ro.outfit_id,
        ro.sub,
        ro.created_at as reaction_created_at
 from outfit
          left join reaction_outfit ro on outfit.id = ro.outfit_id
 where is_public = true
 order by outfit.created_at desc))
order by outfit_created_at desc;
```

Comment: This won't fix anything, as the top half of the union always has priority = 0, while the bottom half has priority = 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Tom Ellyatt, like Tim said its not resolving the issue.